# Using \" as eol-character in a *.bat-file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a .bat-script that prints all variable names in a *.sys-file. The problem is that some of the lines looks like this:

`CONST String strInstructions{22} := [
    "---------------------MESSAGE---------------------",
    "Yaddayadda",
    "   ",
    "--------------------------------------------------",
    "   Yaddayadda",
    "    ",
    "   Yaddayadda",
    "   Yaddayadda",
    "   ",
    "   Yaddayadda",
    " ",
    "---------------------MESSAGE-----------------------",
    " Yaddayadda",
    "          ",
    "--------------------------------------------------",
    "   Yaddayadda",
    "   ",
    "   Yaddayadda",
    "   Yaddayadda",
    "   ",
    "   Yaddayadda",
    " "];`

When I don't have the message rows, the following script works fine ("!" is used for comments):

`@echo off
for /F "eol=! tokens=3 delims=:{ " %%A in (SType_txt.sys) do (
    echo %%A
)`

But I can't for my life figure out how to skip the lines that begin with the `"`-character. When I use `"eol=!"" tokens=3 delims=:{ "` it seems to skip the lines that just contain the character `"`, when I just want to check for the first non-space character. So I guess my question basically is: "How do I use only the first non-space character as eol?"

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to specify `"` as your EOL character, and preserve all your other options, including `<space>` in the list of delimiters.

```
for /f ^"eol^=" tokens=3 delims=:{ " %%A in (SType_txt.sys) do echo %%A
```

But it is not possible to specify two characters for EOL - you could use `"` or `!`, but not both.

The best way forward that I can see is to use FINDSTR to filter out the additional unwanted lines instead.

```
for /F "eol=! tokens=3 delims=:{ " %%A in ('findstr /rvc:"^[:{ ]*\"^" SType_txt.sys') do echo %%A
```